# WP E-commerce and Display Fancy Purchase Notifications

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

I have enabled Display Fancy Purchase Notification for WP E-commerce but it looks like that fancy pop-up window is not working.

Console throws an error

> jQuery( 'form.product_form, .wpsc-add-to-cart-button-form' ).on(
>   'submit', function() {  TypeError: jQuery(...).on is not a function

but add to cart functionality works.

Site is located here: http://www.tozzicollection.com

Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of different scripts running on your pages and it looks like at least one of them has an error.  By the time the wpec js runs, you already have an error.

Comment: It looks like I'm getting those errors from jQuery conflict through wp_head. Possible some plugins.

Comment: I have eliminated all jQuery errors excluding that one mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that theme functions was handled `wp_deregister_script('jquery')` and jQuery loaded from one of plugins was outdated (1.5.2) which was causing all errors. I have removed `wp_deregister_script('jquery')` from the functions.php file and all working as should.